# How to use a jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a Example and source code of a JQuery autocomplete.
for e.g. if i have a cityArray={'Amsterdam, Amritsar, London, New york'};
i want that whenever user press 'N' it will show a All the cities which contains a 'N' character, as per above array it must show London and New York both. I have a example which show all the cities which Starts with 'N' character, but I need all the cities which having a 'N' Character.
please help me. 
Reply me as soon as possible.

Comment: Please increase your Acceptence rate to get more reply. hope it make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can find AutoComplete using jQuery at below mentioned link.

http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2010/02/autocomplete-using-jquery.html

Or You can search with google... and you will find out lots of AutomComplete using JQuery.